# PHP proxy server working half of the time

Tags: php, soap, proxy

I know next to nothing about PHP. I'm trying to give away a set of financial calculators that rely on web service which is accessed via either a .NET proxy or PHP proxy. I've in stalled the PHP proxy on 3 different servers (windows and linux) and the setup always works for me. Yet, I have webmaster write and they can't get it to run.

I was hoping someone with debugging experice can give these a try:

http://www.pine-grove.com/online-calculators/pgs-html-calculators.htm

Here's more background to save you some time.

There an install PDF included. But basically unzip in a folder. Suggest "calculators". Locate js/calculator.js. At about row 11, edit this line to point to the proxy that is installed:

var strWebService = 'http://{www.your-server.com}/Calculators/proxies/calculators.php';

That's all that should be required. The HTTPRequest object's responseText field contains this error:

```
soap:ReceiverServer was unable to process request. ---> '\' is an unexpected token. The expected token is '"' or '''. Line 1, position 15.**
```

This seems to be working for most people, but for a handfull, it doesn't.
thanks in advance and I hope someone can shed some light on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);` is probably not what you want. This causes the response headers to be included *as text* at the head of `$result`. By `echo`ing them back, they do not magically become response headers of the request to `calculator.php`; they are part of the body of the response.
2. A four second timeout is probably too small. If it works for you, but not the webmaster, then I'm guessing that the CURL request performed by `calculator.php` timed out for the webmaster and a warning stating this fact was sent back.
3. These look wrong:

   ```
   $header[] = "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8";
   $header[] = 'http://com.pine-grove/' + $wsMethod;
   ```
4. Get rid of the PHP close tag `?>` at the end. It's generally not needed and you risk sending back extra whitespace, as in this case, where `calculator.php` is inadvertently appending CR+LF to the bodies of all proxied responses.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've made the suggested edits and I'll have the webmaster try the updated proxy and will post back the results. I changed the CURLOPT_HEADER to 0, the time out to 30 and removed the closing PHP tag. Change proxy still works on test server. Will report back later what webmaster says.